# Как правильно передать body в PUT запрос?

Tags: http, ruby, put

Есть код:

```
def table_update
  body = { id: 1, name: 'user1' }
  put "/users", body.to_json, "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"
  assert last_response.ok?

  real_res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '#{body[:name]}'"
  )

  res = parse(data.to_json)
  check_data(res, real_res)
end
```

При выполнении возникает ошибка "Failed assertion, no message given."

Comment: Откройте лог, псмотрите, что ответил сервер. И надеюсь, что у вас интерполяция в запрос только в тестах.

Comment: Какой веб-фреймворк используется?

Comment: И `data` откуда берётся?